# Symfony, how get current user (FOS) in entity, unused __construct()?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity, relationships, magic-methods

I have an entity `Book`. Title of this `Book` is stored in different languages ​​(the entity `Book` is associated with `BookTranslates` as `OneToMane`).

The entity `Book` is used as a form field in several places (like select). For this, I need to set `__toString ()` for the `Book` entity, which will return the title of the `Book` in the user's language.

I tried to get the user inside the entity by passing `TokenStorageInterface` in the `__construct ()` method of the `Book` class, but the doctrine never calls the `__construct ()` method in that case.

Brief statement of the problem:
`__toString ()` in entity must return a field of one of the related entities. Which specifically related entities - depends on the current user. How to implement it correctly?

Comment: i recommend to use https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/v2.4.x/doc/translatable.md  dont let the entity translate it self

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the possible solutions:

Please leave entity `__construct` alone.

I assume you have entity with `translations`. You entity can (should) have method like `setCurrentLocale` to be aware of current locale. Method can be called manually or in e.g. `Doctrine2 postLoad` event:

```
public function setCurrentLocale(string $locale)
{
    $this->locale - $locale;
}
```

Now in `__toString` while translating e.g. `title` your entity can fetch proper translation.